# How do I disable the message "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell" message when running Powershell after latest windows update

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Since the latest Windows 10 update, when opening Powershell I get the message "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6".

I would like to turn that notification off.  Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of this  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053189/how-do-i-disable-personal-and-system-profiles-loding-time-message-on-powershell) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/645721/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-powershell-banner-message)?

Comment: Not exactly, though that does get rid of the message, it gets rid of the other banner information as well.  I would like to preserve the `Loading personal and system profiles took xxx ms` message.

Answer (score 11):

Modify your PowerShell shortcut to include the -NoLogo switch.

Comment: Not exactly, though that does get rid of the message, it gets rid of the other banner information as well. I would like to preserve the Loading personal and system profiles took xxx ms message.

Comment: By the way, the message about how long it took to load your profile only appears if PowerShell thinks it took too long.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell always starts your profile script located in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

You can use this script to replace the message entirely.

For example, you can put the following script there:

```
cls
write-host "Windows PowerShell"
write-host "Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
write-host ""
```

Although the banner will be shown for less than a millisecond, this will work. It is possible to start Powershell with the `-nologo` switch which will remove that flash of banner altogether and then print this banner instead.

The message can of course be adjusted. This file can also be used to store custom functions and you can even create a function called Prompt to replace the default Powershell prompt.

This script is always loaded at the start of the powershell launch, even if you use Windows Terminal, though it will not reload the profile script in Windows Terminal if you open a new instance. The one cached from memory will be played instead.

Answer (score 0):

locate this path C:\Users<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 or create it manually if does not exist

and then add cls at the top of the file (Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) and save

this will clear the page immedatly after you lunch your powershell

Answer (score -3):

Open file location and add "**-nologo**" behind
[change msg powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLwM.png)

Comment: This exact solution was already suggested back in 2019